# Woocommerce Product finder feature on home page

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

We use woocommerce and came across a "product finder" using filters on this home page. https://funandfunction.com/

We use the WOOF - WooCommerce Products Filter to  filter products on our product category pages, but we haven't been able to find a way of allowing customers to search directly on the home page.

Has anyone come across a plugin which will allow for such a feature or does it require developing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a plugin that allows AJAX search on product post type, there are many:

1. [SearchWP](https://searchwp.com/): AJAX, a bit complex and premium, but for me it is the best.
2. [Ajax search lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/): It allows to customize layouts and search on woocommerce products on the free version.
3. [Ajax search for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-for-woocommerce/): Good layout, free, reliable.

In any case you will have to customize the plugin and adapt it to your needs and layout. All of the above will allow you to search from the frontpage of your website.